# CreatePen returning NULL on window resizing

Tags: c, windows, winapi

So I am experimenting with Win32 API and trying to plot a line with colour gradient (*by creating a custom Pen*). The code is working fine and I am getting my desired result but when I start resizing my window, `CreatePen()` function starts giving `NULL` value, and thus Windows start using the default black pen.

This is my `WndProc` code:

*(https://pastebin.com/xiyzX5fu for full code)*

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int cxClient, cyClient;
    HDC hdc;
    HPEN hPen;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_SIZE:
        cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
        cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        return 0;
 
    case WM_PAINT:
        printf("%d\t%d\n", cxClient, cyClient); //Printing the resolution
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        MoveToEx(hdc, 0, cyClient / 2, NULL);
        int count = 0;
 
        //Plotting 256 lines each of length (cxClient/256) with different color
        for (int i = 0; i < cxClient; i += cxClient / 256)
        {
            if ((hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 10, RGB(count, 255, 255))) == NULL)
            {
                DWORD lasterror;
                lasterror = GetLastError();
                printf("We got a NULL Value and last error code was %lu\n", lasterror);
                break;
            }
            else
                SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
 
            count += 1; // For uniform color gradient across width
            LineTo(hdc, i, cyClient / 2);
        }
        DeleteObject(hPen);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
 
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

**I am trying to debug it for the last few hours and here are some of my observations:**

- My calculation for `RGB` are correct. In fact, even a default pen
  `CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, 0x00000000)` leads to same error.
- The error is more profound if the increment value is smaller, i.e.
  for `i += cxClient/5` *(plots only 5 lines)* `CreatePen` would return
  NULL values much less often while resizing as compared to `i += cxClient/256` *(plots 256 lines)*
  (Line 59)
- **Interesting One:** I print the size of my Client Area using `printf` (Line 53). The moment `CreatePen()` returns a NULL value,
  the console will stop printing the statement containing the Client
  Area and will only print the NULL error statement (Line 65) again and again. It will
  print both only when I add a `break` (Line 66) after printing the
  NULL error statement.
- I think I am not able to capture the error of `CreatePen()` using
  `GetlastError()` (Line 64) correctly because it always prints 0
  `(ERROR_SUCCESS)` on the console.

Based on these observations I think the problem doesn't lie in `CreatePen()` but in my way of calculating the length of each line.

Comment: You are leaking pen handles. And eventually you exhaust available GDI resources. Note that you call CreatePen inside a loop. GetLastError returns 0 because CreatePen is not contracted to call SetLastError. This can be gleaned from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the pen, selecting it into the dc, and then deleting it while it is still selected in the dc. This will case `DeleteObject` to [fail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject#return-value). You need to remember the old pen that was selected, and then select that back into the dc before deleting your pen:

```
HPEN oldPen;
...
oldPen = SelectObject(hdc, hPen);
...
SelectObject(hdc, oldPen);
DeleteObject(hPen);
```

Comment: That code needs to be inside the loop, worth noting that

Comment: It worked like a charm. I added the code you suggested, inside the loop (as instructed by David Heffernan) Thank you both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are leaking GDI object. When the number of GDI objects in your process reaches 10,000, the system will no longer allow the creation of new GDI objects. This is why `hPen` will eventually return NULL.

> Furthermore, as we saw last time, the maximum number of window manager
> objects that can be created is around 32,700. Giving a program 10,000
> is already a third of the total amount available. That’s already
> pretty darned generous, if you ask me. Preventing a program from
> running away and consuming all of the window manager objects is an
> attempt to contain the damage caused by a runaway program. Even if a
> program goes haywire, there’s still around 20,000 objects available
> for the other programs to use.

Refer: [Why is the limit of window handles per process 10,000?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070718-00/?p=25963)

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that perfectly explains getting NULL values faster with low increment value as compared to high increment value in the loop.

Comment: @ImperfeKt  Yes, I hope you know the real reason why hPen returns NULL:)